# mvc Posting Class Based off Abstract class

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, abstract-class

my problem is i have an abstract class that when used is binding to the page correctly but when i try to post the model (a fully formed class based on the abstract class) back to the controller the properties of the abstract class are not getting populated.

the way i am implementing is as following

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private int _property1;
    public int Property1
    {
        get{
            return _property1;
        }
        set{
            _property1=value;
        }
    }

}
public class ImplementClass:BaseClass
{
    public ImplementClass()
    {
    }
}
```

the controller is

```
public class Ctrler:Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoSomthing()
    {}
    [HTTPPOST]
    public ActionResult DoSomthing(ImplementClass model)
    {
        //...doSomthing with class but the property1 has a value of 0 and debugging will never set the Property on the class
    }
}
```

the View is

```
@model ImplementClass
@(using(Html.BeginForm("DoSomthing","Ctrler"), FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frm1", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Property1,new {@Value="1"})
    </div>
    <input type="Submit" Value="Submit"/>
}
```

the submit is via Ajax and the code is somthing like.

```
$(function(){
$('form').bind('submit',submitForm);

function submitForm()
{
    var submitForm = $('form');

    var data = submitForm.serializeObject();
        $.ajax(submitForm.prop('action'), 
        {
            cached: false,
            type: 'POST',
            //              dataType: 'json',
            //              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: data,
            success: function (response)
            {
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    return false;
}
});
```

[Edit]
I have found the problem it was my own stupidity, i had a protected SET on the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To diagnose any issues with the ModelBinder (which populates the parameters to Controller Actions), you are able to step through MVC code.

See http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/04/stepping-into-asp-net-mvc-source-code-with-visual-studio-debugger.aspx for more details.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i need for things like this.